# Why is my locked record editable?

Tags: apex, controller, permissions, dml, record

1. Why is my record locked? I created a record, but, when shown in detail view, it has the 'locked' icon, and appears to be locked at first view, but-
2. Why can I edit the locked record (Even as a standard user)? The record is completely editable. I have no idea why this is occurring- or why the record is actually not locked.

[image: locked png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) why is the record locked

I do not see the code use any locking statements, not sure if there are 2 record types used in your org for locking and unlocking if the above 2 statements don't apply:

Check if there is an approval process on the object and in check if there is a final approve action/ final reject action that says

> Record Lock   Lock the record from being edited

2) Check who can edit the records :

This gives you the answer to why you can still edit the record even as a standard user ( login as a user who is not the submitter of the record or the owner and try to edit, you should get a record locked error)

> Record Editability
>
> Administrators ONLY can edit records during the approval process.
>
> (or)
>
> Administrators OR the currently assigned approver can edit records
>   during the approval process.

Comment: "Locking Statements" wouldn't show a lock icon, so that bit is off.

Comment: See that's why I'm confused- I couldn't find a process that salesforce had in place to lock a record other then an approval process, and there was no approval process on that object. However, I did find out why there was a lock- see my marked answer.

Answer (score 0):

This record is locked because a parent record is locked- for some reason, this record is editable by everyone, while the parent record is System Administrator only. I missed this, because I was testing an approval process on a different sandbox for a different issue, and forgot I had tried an alternate fix on this sandbox. This fixed one issue, but now, my workflow rules don't seem to be firing on records created by this method- but that's an issue for a separate question. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: you mean the child record of a locked parent is editable but both the child and parent records show the lock icon?

Comment: Correct. Its something to do with the org settings, and the user permissions, I think, but it doesn't matter now, my administrator said its fine for it to be the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

If record is lock and you are not an admin, approver or owner then check for profile setting if it is "modify all" enable for you.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contribution is welcome, but it seems to me that you did not read the details of the question. Your answer might help someone who has an uneditable record, but the OP's issue was a record that had a locked icon but which was actually editable. That is different. You might want to voluntarily delete this answer, as there is a chance it gets downvoted and/or deleted. Feel free to keep contributing to SFSE! *Be sure to [take the Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help).*